# Ubuntu 20.04, Bluetooth True wireless headphones not working (work in previous version) Sony WF-1000XM3

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, headphones, sony

First of all, sorry for my poor English.

I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, clean installation, and my bluetooth headphones stop working/connecting.

- I put them in pairing mode, Ubuntu recognized them.
- if I click on connect, Ubuntu says that it is 'connected'.
- BUT the headphones on connect always say 'Bluetooth Connected' on their speaker. And in this case, nothing. I think the headphone stays in pairing mode.

The headphones are Sony WF-1000XM3. My last version of Ubuntu was 18.04 LTE and it works and connects with no problems at all.

I can provide logs if you need.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: no :( can't find a workarround

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. reading your question I realized that you were right, the headphones never warned me that it was connected so they were still in pairing mode.

Once the pairing was done I turned them off, then turned them on again and it worked without problems.

Greetings my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I was able to resolve it by using the  `bluetoothctl`

just connect to the tool and remove the record of the device that fail to connect

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]#show
[bluetooth]#devices 
[bluetooth]#remove <mac address of the device with the issue>
```

attempt to connect now

Comment: Fixed my issue!